# Maven dependency issue in Mule project

Tags: maven, mule

I'm not able to find this particular maven dependency while creating new Maven support enabled project in AnypointStudio. Same issue comes when I try to mavenize an existing Mule project. Has anyone solved this?
Anypoint Studio version - 5.4.3
Mule runtime version - 3.6.1

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:copy (copy-clover-plugins) on project tradeshift-connector: Unable to find artifact. Failure to find com.cloveretl:cloveretl-engine:zip:3.6.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Central has elapsed or updates are forced
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.cloveretl -DartifactId=cloveretl-engine -Dversion=3.6.1 -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.cloveretl -DartifactId=cloveretl-engine -Dversion=3.6.1 -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] com.cloveretl:cloveretl-engine:zip:3.6.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] mulesoft-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

Comment: I faced this issue and asked for help. Some one didn't like it and voted it down. Don't understand what was wrong.

Comment: Just comment out that dependency. Most of the times we dont use it although it appears by default in pom.xml when you create a new maven project

Comment: there are some more repositories available from where you will be able to download these dependencies (like nexus repo for mule or ibiblio repository for mule)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local M2_REPO folder and delete contents of /com/cloveretl. That will force Maven to pull it again.

Comment: Didn't help. But an update is that it successfully downloaded this dependency when I changed to Mule version 3.7.3 from Mule EE repository. This is leading me to believe that version 3.6.1 do not exist in repo. Not sure how can I verify it.

Comment: I don't think Mule Version would matter if you are trying to access a particular dependency jar. I looked into mule releases-ee repo and can see cloveretl 3.6.1 zip at below location -   https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/cloveretl/cloveretl-engine/3.6.1/cloveretl-engine-3.6.1.zip. You would need your EE credentials to access this url.

Comment: Your logs in question shows - http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/ ... which is not enterprise repo and do not contain clover etl. You can browse it in browser to verify.

Comment: When I try to fetch 3.6.1, it downloads 3.6.0 RC1 zip but nothing in 3.6.1. This is quite strange considering 3.6.1 exists there as you see it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your local .m2 repo and delete the contents of /com/cloveretl, as others have suggested.

Mule recreates the folder correctly but the ZIP file is called cloveretl-engine-3.6.1.zip.**lastupdated**.

Rename to cloveretl-engine-3.6.1.zip and it works fine.